# Sign of potential in double Atwood machine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, potential, string

I'm feeling very confused about which sign to the potential should I choose. A specific exercise I've had trouble with is in [this link](http://www.web.uvic.ca/~rdesousa/teaching/P321A/L27_321A.pdf).
in this exercise a double Atwood machine is given. when I tried calculating the potential, I drew gravity pointing downwards, and the axis system I chose was y pointing downwards and x pointing right. I chose the reference plane to be the canter of the top pulley (marked in green in the picture). so when I calculated the total potential energy V, for all the masses, I got the same expression as in the article, but in an opposite sign. What did I miss?

Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

---

edit: that's how I tried to solve this:
[image]

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: @FissionChips I've added my solution (at least what Iv'e tried to do). thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Co-ordinate systems for 1D vectors are always tricky. A handy technique to validate your co-ordinate system is to track the potential energy of a particle under free fall (in your co-ordinate system).

The direction of $g$ has to be such that the potential energy is decreasing as energy has to be conserved. (Kinetic energy depends only on the magnitude of $v$ which keeps increasing under free fall). This is violated in your co-ordinate frame unless $g\to-g$. If you do so, then your Lagrangians will match.